# Angular 1.5 ngMaterial Karma Unit testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angularjs-material

I have introduced ngMaterial in our app using AngularJS 1.5 version. Everything looks good but karma test case fails with message

> "Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it."

Below is my code. Can someone please help with this error.

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  var myComponentComponent = {
    templateUrl: 'app/myComp/myComp.html',
    controller: myComponentController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  };

  /* @ngInject */
  function myComponentController($sce, $templateCache, viewport) {
    var vm = this;

  }

  angular.module('core', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
    .component('myComponent', myComponentComponent);

})(angular);
```

---

```
describe('testCore', function () {
  beforeEach(module('core'));
  beforeEach(module('ngMaterial'));
  beforeEach(module('ngMessages'));

  var $window;
  var $componentController;
  var scope;
  var $rootScope;
  var controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$window_, _$componentController_, _$rootScope_) {
    $window = _$window_;
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $componentController('myComponent', null, scope.mockData);
    scope.$apply();
  }));



  it('should initialize component', function () {

  });


});
```

Comment: When you receive this error, check that the name of the module in question is correct and that the file in which this module is defined has been loaded (either via `<script>` tag, loader like require.js, or testing harness like karma). [1](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod)

Comment: @georgeawg  thank you. I was using  script tags before and now i moved them to my package.json and added dependencies in karma conf. The issue is resolved. 

Now i am facing different issue like userAgent.match is not a function from angular-material.js file. Any thoughts why this could this happen ?